# rm and Garbage Collection Wrapper

Tags: r, garbage-collection, wrapper

How would I make a function named `rm2` that takes in an unknown number of objects, removes them, and then runs the `gc()`?

I have tried a could things but cannot figure it out.

```
rm2 <- function(...){
  #files <- list(...)
  #files <- list(deparse(substitute(...)))
  #rm(list = files)
  rm(...)
  capture.output(gc(),file='NUL')
}
```

I would appreciate it.

Also, lets try to not bring up the `gc()` complaints.  I find that it does help to free up RAM to my host OS :)

Comment: Have you tried using the `envir` argument of `rm` in your `rm2` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option is to do as `rm` itself does and use the `...` from the matched call (from `match.call`). This gives a list of symbols, which I then convert to a character vector using `sapply`. This vector is then passed to `rm` as argument `list`. Finally we just return the output from `gc`:

```
rm2 <- function(...) {
  dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
  dots <- sapply(dots, as.character)
  rm(list = dots, envir = globalenv())
  gc()
}

> ls()
[1] "pred" "reg4" "rm2"  "tenv" "x"    "y"   
> rm2(x, y)
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 226670 12.2     467875   25   350000 18.7
Vcells 357248  2.8     905753    7   867363  6.7
> ls()
[1] "pred" "reg4" "rm2"  "tenv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe this:

```
rm2 <- function(...) {
    x <- substitute(...())
    Trim <- function (x) gsub("\\s+$", "", x)
    z <- Trim(unlist(lapply(x, function(y) as.character(y))))
    rm(list=z, envir =  .GlobalEnv)
    capture.output(gc())
}
```

PS use `NULL` not `'NUL'` though the default is to use `NULL` any way so it's not necessary to include it.

Comment: I don't think there is much use for the `capture.output` - just returning `gc()` should be fine.

Comment: Didn't know why the OP harbor just left it in.

Comment: Ah - missed that.  But to be honest I think they were just trying to direct the output to someplace they didn't need to see it.  Wrapping `gc` in `invisible()` is probably the best solution IMO.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
rm2 <- function(...) {
    Call <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
    Call[[1L]] <- as.name("rm")
    eval.parent(Call)
    gc(verbose = FALSE, reset = TRUE)
    NULL
}
```

First part is based on `write.csv` function. Then you do `gc` with verbose set to `FALSE` to prevent printing info. At the end function returns `NULL` (without it it would print result of `gc` which is summary of memory cleanup).

Comment: Marek,  I like this approach, too.  Thank you.  also, thanks for the NULL hints!

Comment: I think this is a really awful programming technique and wish `write.csv` did not use it.  (Also returning the output of rm would be even better)